# Class path.config does not exist - Lumen 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, lumen-5.2

i have a little problem while adding GoogleMaps Package By alexpechkarev 
link : https://alexpechkarev.github.io/google-maps/ to lumen framework version 5.2
I added the ServiceProvider and Facade to my app.php :

```
$app->register(GoogleMaps\ServiceProvider\GoogleMapsServiceProvider::class);

class_alias(GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade::class, 'GoogleMaps');
```

but when, I go to my command line and tape : php artisan I get this error message :

> [ReflectionException] Class path.config does not exist

Answer (score 14):

It is trying to resolve `path.config` from the IoC container, but it hasn't been defined.

Somewhere before you register your `GoogleMapsServiceProvider`, you need to add that value to your container.

```
$app->instance('path.config', app()->basePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');
```

Comment: This solved my issue also after update to php7.1 thanks